# Bootstrap 3 typeahead From returned webservice list

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

This is a return xml list from a webservice:

```
public async Task<SelectResponse> AutoSearchService(string filter)
    {
        SelectResponse ResponseData = new SelectResponse();
        var Url = string.Format("{0}{1}", "serviceURL", filter);
        var Client = new HttpClient();
        Client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Url.ToString());
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
        var ResponseMessage = await Client.GetAsync(Url.ToString());
        if (ResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            //Get Tickets from Banner 
            ResponseData = ResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<SelectResponse>().Result;
        }
        return ResponseData;
    }
```

and it get an xml data like this:

```html
<SelectResponse>
  <SelectResult>
    <STVSBGIRECORDSELECT>
      <STVSBGI_DESC>Holback Handelsskole</STVSBGI_DESC>
    </STVSBGIRECORDSELECT>
    <STVSBGIRECORDSELECT>
      <STVSBGI_DESC>Los Gatos High Sch.-Los Gatos</STVSBGI_DESC>
    </STVSBGIRECORDSELECT>
    <STVSBGIRECORDSELECT>
      <STVSBGI_DESC>Rich East High Sch.</STVSBGI_DESC>
    </STVSBGIRECORDSELECT>
  </SelectResult>
</SelectResponse>
```

Then i need to add it to the query list in the following jquery code instead of the local values:

```js
$('#query').typeahead({
        local: ['alpha', 'allpha2', 'alpha3', 'bravo', 'charlie', 'delta', 'epsilon', 'gamma', 'zulu']
    });
```

What should i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to create/add to the local property of typeahead the values of STVSBGI_DESC tags you can do:

```js
//
// Let's assume this is the xml as string you receive from your server
//
var str = '<SelectResponse>\
<SelectResult>\
<STVSBGIRECORDSELECT>\
<STVSBGI_DESC>Holback Handelsskole<\/STVSBGI_DESC>\
<\/STVSBGIRECORDSELECT>\
<STVSBGIRECORDSELECT>\
<STVSBGI_DESC>Los Gatos High Sch.-Los Gatos<\/STVSBGI_DESC>\
<\/STVSBGIRECORDSELECT>\
<STVSBGIRECORDSELECT>\
<STVSBGI_DESC>Rich East High Sch.</STVSBGI_DESC>\
<\/STVSBGIRECORDSELECT>\
<\/SelectResult>\
<\/SelectResponse>';


var localVar = ['alpha', 'allpha2', 'alpha3', 'bravo', 'charlie', 'delta', 'epsilon', 'gamma', 'zulu'];


//
// Use jQuery parseXML to convert it to an xml doc
//
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(str);

//
// using jQuery iterate on tags adding value to your variable
//
$(xmlDoc).find('STVSBGI_DESC').each(function(index, value) {
  localVar.push(value.textContent);
});

console.log('the new value is: ' + localVar);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

An alternative is to use [source: function(query) {....](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead)  instead of local.